# how to align div below each other

Tags: html, css

I want to align my Divs as "composite timeline" (header1) div on left

image div ( header 2 ) to float right .

and "this is div2" div just below these two with 12px space between them. I have tried to do but failed and I don't want to give margin of "this is div2" div from top , i want it relative to the header1 and header2 divs.

here is the code.

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">
<body>
<div id="header1Main">
<div id="header1">Composite Timeline</div>
<div id="header2"><img src="images/drop-down-arrow.png"></img></div>
</div>
<div class="div2Main">this is div 2</div>
<div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
#header1Main
{

}
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    left: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
}

#header2 
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main
{
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left:12px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image as to how exactly you want your divs to be positioned?

Comment: @dilip 

I want that "div2Main" div come just below the line of hearder1 and header2 divs 

Here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/678n2837/

Answer (score 1):

Add a clearing `div` between them and give the div a height of `12px`

**HTML**

```
<div id="header1Main">
<div id="header1">Composite Timeline</div>
<div id="header2"><img src="images/drop-down-arrow.png"></img></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div2Main">this is div 2</div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
#header1Main
{

}
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    left: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
}

#header2 
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main
{
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left:12px;
}

.clear { clear:both; height: 12px; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cj2L947/)

Answer (score 1):

remove float:left from #header1 in css and its done

```
// HTML


<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">
<body>
<div id="header1Main">
<div id="header1">Composite Timeline</div>
<div id="header2"><img src="images/drop-down-arrow.png"></img></div>
</div>
<div class="div2Main">this is div 2</div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>




//CSS


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
#header1Main
{

}
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    left: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

#header2 
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main
{
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clean up your markup it was invalid and image tag is `<img src= />`

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
#header1Main
{

}
#header1 {
    display:block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    left: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
}

#header2 
{
    display:block;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main
{
    display: block;
    background-color: aqua;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">
<body>
  
<div id="header1Main">
    <div id="header1">Composite Timeline</div>
    <div id="header2">
        <img src="images/drop-down-arrow.png"/>   
    </div>
    <div class="div2Main">this is div 2</div>
</div> 
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand what right and float means.
Anyway... here's the code

http://jsfiddle.net/t0o2pwn5/

Change your css like this.

```
#header1Main {
    display: block;
}

#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

#header2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 12px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main {
    display:block;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left:12px;
}
```